# Magento: Creating new Attributes with Options

Tags: php, magento

I am creating a simple import script for attributes and I cannot figure out how to add options to them. Every attribute of the 'Attribute' is straight forward, except for adding an option. Is this something that can be done upon the creation of an Attribute??

The code I use basically is below.

```
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute');  
$data = array(
    'is_global'                     => '0',
    'frontend_input'                => 'text',
    'default_value_text'            => '',
    'default_value_yesno'           => '0',
    'default_value_date'            => '',
    'default_value_textarea'        => '',
    'is_unique'                     => '0',
    'is_required'                   => '0',
    'frontend_class'                => '',
    'is_searchable'                 => '1',
    'is_visible_in_advanced_search' => '1',
    'is_comparable'                 => '1',
    'is_used_for_promo_rules'       => '0',
    'is_html_allowed_on_front'      => '1',
    'is_visible_on_front'           => '0',
    'used_in_product_listing'       => '0',
    'used_for_sort_by'              => '0',
    'is_configurable'               => '0',
    'is_filterable'                 => '0',
    'is_filterable_in_search'       => '0',
    'backend_type'                  => 'varchar',
    'default_value'                 => '',
    'frontend_label'                => '',
    'attribute_code'                => ''
);  
foreach ($header as $key => $value){
    if(isset($data[$key]) !== false){
        $data[$key] = $row[$header[$key]];
    }
}

$data['option'] = ?WHAT DO I DO HERE¿

$model->addData($data); 
$model->setEntityTypeId(Mage::getModel('eav/entity')->setType('catalog_product')->getTypeId());

$model->setIsUserDefined(1);
$model->save();
```

}

EDIT:

Thanks to Marko for his example, I tried the following;

```
$data['option'] = array (
        'value' => array(
                'wood' => array('Wood'),
                'metal' => array('Metal')
        )
);
```

His method for adding attributes in general is slightly different but the value for that attribute works just the same.

W00t!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create sql script (tutorial: http://alanstorm.com/magento_setup_resources) and inside put something like:

```
$installer = $this;
$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();

$setup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'attr_code', array(
    'group'         => 'General',
    'input'         => 'select',
    'type'          => 'text',
    'label'         => 'Material',
    'backend'       => '',
    'visible'       => 1,
    'required'      => 0,
    'user_defined' => 1,
    'searchable' => 1,
    'filterable' => 0,
    'comparable'    => 1,
    'visible_on_front' => 1,
    'source' => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_table',
    'visible_in_advanced_search'  => 0,
    'is_html_allowed_on_front' => 0,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'configurable' => 1,
    'option'  => array (
            'value' => array(
                    'wood' => array('Wood'),
                    'metal' => array('Metal')
            )
    ),
));

$installer->endSetup();
```

this should create attribute Material with Wood and Metal options

Comment: I am writing a CLI script, what context is the $this variable?

Comment: $this variable is actually instance of the class Digramm_Productvariants_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup. It's explained by Alan Storm in the tutorial which I posted above.